# Indicators Menu Missing In Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, indicator

Recently I have upgraded gedit to 3.12 ( gnome 3.12 , only Gedit ), My indicators menus are gone. I can see the indicator but no menu

> How do I fix it ?

**Indicators**
[image]

**Show Menu**
[image] **Nothing**

> **Updated**

Bluetooth, Mail , Battery and Date Menu **not appearing**

Skype, Network Manager and other Indicator **menu does appear**.

Comment: How did you go about just upgrading Gedit? It seems unlikely that the indicators would use something in Gedit so I'm suggesting that somewhere along the line, you've upgraded something else that has done the breaking.

Comment: sudo apt-get install gedit gedit-plugins < it upgraded the gedit

Comment: have you changed your GTK theme recently? Not all of them are complete or have colors that account for every instance.

Comment: i am using the theme from past 4 5 days with no issue

Answer (score 0):

- Try restart Unity panel service:

  ```
  killall unity-panel-service
  ```